# phpmorphy - поиск с учетом русской морфологии

Tags: php

Есть проблема, не пойму откуда и из-за чего она появляется.

```
require_once(codes::get('path') . 'phpmorphy/src/common.php');
$dict_bundle = new phpMorphy_FilesBundle(codes::get('path') . 'phpmorphy/dicts', 'rus');
$morphy = new phpMorphy($dict_bundle, array(
    'storage' => PHPMORPHY_STORAGE_MEM
));
$text = 'Примерный запрос поиска';
$q = explode(' ', mb_strtoupper($text));
$base_form = $morphy->getBaseForm($q); 
$all_forms = $morphy->getAllForms($q); 
$pseudo_root = $morphy->getPseudoRoot($q);
a::b($q, $base_form, $all_forms, $pseudo_root); // a::b - print_r, крутой только.
```

Результат выполнения php.

```
Array
(
    [0] => ПРИМЕРНЫЙ
    [1] => ЗАПРОС
    [2] => ПОИСКА
)
Array
(
    [ПРИМЕРНЫЙ] => Array
        (
            [0] => ПРИМЕРНЫЙ
        )

    [ПОИСКА] => Array
        (
            [0] => ПОИСКА
        )

    [ЗАПРОС] => Array
        (
            [0] => ЗАПРОС
        )

)
Array
(
    [ПРИМЕРНЫЙ] => Array
        (
            [0] => ПРИМЕРНЫЙ
            [1] => ПРИМЕРНОГО
            [2] => ПРИМЕРНОМУ
            [3] => ПРИМЕРНЫМ
            [4] => ПРИМЕРНОМ
            [5] => ПРИМЕРНЫЕ
            [6] => ПРИМЕРНЫХ
            [7] => ПРИМЕРНЫМИ
            [8] => ПРИМЕРНАЯ
            [9] => ПРИМЕРНОЙ
            [10] => ПРИМЕРНУЮ
            [11] => ПРИМЕРНОЮ
            [12] => ПРИМЕРНОЕ
        )

    [ПОИСКА] => Array
        (
            [0] => ПОИСКА
            [1] => ПОИСКИ
            [2] => ПОИСКЕ
            [3] => ПОИСКУ
            [4] => ПОИСКОЙ
            [5] => ПОИСКОЮ
            [6] => ПОИСОК
            [7] => ПОИСКАМ
            [8] => ПОИСКАМИ
            [9] => ПОИСКАХ
        )

    [ЗАПРОС] => Array
        (
            [0] => ЗАПРОС
            [1] => ЗАПРОСА
            [2] => ЗАПРОСУ
            [3] => ЗАПРОСОМ
            [4] => ЗАПРОСЕ
            [5] => ЗАПРОСЫ
            [6] => ЗАПРОСОВ
            [7] => ЗАПРОСАМ
            [8] => ЗАПРОСАМИ
            [9] => ЗАПРОСАХ
        )

)
Array
(
    [ПРИМЕРНЫЙ] => Array
        (
            [0] => ПРИМЕРН
        )

    [ПОИСКА] => Array
        (
            [0] => ПОИС
        )

    [ЗАПРОС] => Array
        (
            [0] => ЗАПРОС
        )

)
```

Массивы отличаются с теми, что указаны в посте где я беру информацию - [поиск с учетом морфологии русского языка](http://www.manhunter.ru/webmaster/451_poisk_s_uchetom_morfologii_russkogo_yazika.html). Задавал разные опции в phpmorphy, писал разные локали (setlocale) результат тот же.

Может кто знает решение проблемы?

Comment: >> Результат выполнения php.

>> Массивы отличаются с теми, что указаны в посте

что то вы недоговариваете.

Comment: Что не понятно? Массивы по ссылке.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.

Comment: Вопрос можно закрывать, сделал с помощью другой кодировки и более старой версий библиотеки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего какая-то засада со словом `ПОИСК` так как `getAllForms` генерит лишнее `ПОИСОК` там быть не должно. Скорее всего что-то исправили с момента написания статьи :-) Попробуйте взять базу более ранней версии

Comment: Кодировки эти еще.